# FMP - Forcing Save of Field Edit

Tags: filemaker

I'm working on a FileMaker Pro 10 database. On a particular layout ("license"), there are several fields and a button. When the button is clicked, a certificate (layout) is displayed reflecting the data entered in the license layout.

If I edit a field, then immediately click on the "View Certificate" button, the changes just made to the field do not appear on the certificate. However, if I edit the field, then click on another field, then click "View Certificate," the revised data is displayed on the certificate. Apparently, something about shifting focus to a different field triggers a data save.

How can I force this data save so that any time the user clicks on the button, the resulting certificate reflects the edits they have made?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the script that is called on your "View Cerficiate" button, try adding a "Commit Record/Request" script step.